# Как получить доступ к phpMyAdmin локально

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apache, phpmyadmin, apache2

Я установил на VPS Ubuntu Server `apache2` и `phpMyAdmin`

Появилась phpMyAdmin на публичном ip (`ip/phpmyadmin`)

Как сделать, чтобы к этой phpMyAdmin можно так же было зайти локально 127.0.0.1 (`localhost/phpmyadmin`)?

Comment: Установи апач и пхпмайадмин локально

Comment: *Как сделать, чтобы к этой phpMyAdmin можно так же было зайти локально 127.0.0.1* Для этого веб-сервер, через который осуществляется доступ к phpMyAdmin, должен обслуживать и localhost.